# How to retrieve user Firstname and Last name and map it to ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Good day everyone,

The below Index method works well but I need to alter it to display `last name and first name` in View index.

The pictured index view displays `Date, UserId and Total Price.`

Now I got a new requirement to display the user Last name and Surname rather than the `UserId.`

This is my Index Method in the controller.

Books table has a field called `CreateByUser` which is a `UserId` (Guid type)
and the UserManager table has many info including Firstname and Last name that I need here.
I've got `UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager` injected in this controller.

Can you please assist me?

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var bookData = await _context.Books.Select(books => new BookViewModel
        {
            BookId = books.BookId,
            CreateByUser = books.CreateByUser,
            CreatedDate = books.CreatedDate,
            TotalPrice = books.TotalPrice
        }).ToListAsync();

        return View(bookData);
    }
```

Comment: Depending on how you have set up your models, you could include the `User` object in your queries using `Include(NavigationProperty)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a function that gets the user first name and last name by User Id. Something like:

```
public Task<ApplicationUser> GetUsername(string id)
    {
        return DbContext.Set<ApplicationUser>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(user => user.Id == id);
    }
```

Comment: I thought ASP.Net Core Identity doesn't have a DbContext, since the beginning I was working on ` UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;`.  **So what is the difference between both ? (Identity DbContext and UserManager)**

Comment: I assumed you take the data from the database and my answer uses a database context to get the username with that id from the identity "Users" table. The context I am referring to is the one made by you for example ( to be used by entity framework, for  example)